# Why does slices.Delete() in golang copy the next element?

Tags: go, slice, go-modules

Sample code:

```
func main() {
    bar := []string{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"}
    slices.Delete(bar, 0, 1) // I want to delete 'Monday'
    fmt.Println(bar)         // prints [Tuesday Wednesday Wednesday]
}
```

I don't understand why I get a copy of 'Wednesday'. I was expecting a two-element slice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slices.Delete` returns the modified slice. You should use it as:

```
bar=slices.Delete(bar, 0, 1)
```

This is because the delete operation shifts the elements in the slice, and then returns a shorter slice, but the original slice `bar` remains the same.

Comment: So there are two steps (three?) where the first is to remove the element(s), the second is to move everything which needs to move left the right number of steps, and then it returns an array with the shorter slice of the original slice. And it won't warn you that you're using it with its return value being discarded.

Comment: Not exactly. slices.Delete simply shifts the elements over to those that are removed, and returns a shortened slice.